# What interesting open source software is written in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I was looking looking for the sources of real-life applications that are written in Lisp. For example a Pacman clone or a word processor would qualify as such.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about a

- [web server?](http://weitz.de/hunchentoot/)
- [text editor?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemlock_%28editor%29)
- [a type setter?](http://www.cliki.net/cl-typesetting)
- [an interactive musical score editing application?](http://www.cliki.net/Gsharp)

More example can be had at the [cliki](http://www.cliki.net/index). Just stroll around a little bit.

Comment: I would add a [web browser](http://common-lisp.net/project/closure/), another [text editor](http://common-lisp.net/project/climacs/) and a [visual programming language](http://blocky.io/).

Comment: @Pavel - I accept your challenge and raise you another [algebra system](http://www.cliki.net/Axiom), a [tetris clone](http://www.lamirault.info/nicolas/projects/cletris/) and [a rogue like](http://sourceforge.net/projects/langband/) :-)

Comment: Not to mention cliki itself...

Answer (score 2):

The package-management application (similar to apt-get) that I use for Arch Linux, [Paktahn](https://github.com/skypher/paktahn), is written in Common Lisp.

Comment: Now that you mention it... How about [quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [list of applications](http://www.cliki.net/Application) written in Common Lisp. How "real world" they are is debatable, but since you consider a pacman clone to be "real world", I assume you will be satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Two big things come to mind.

```
EMACS
Maxima
```

The first has an incredible number of customizations. It would not surprise me in the least to find Pac-Man implemented in EMACS. Maxima does symbolic mathematics, so I imagine it'd be more difficult to grok the code.